# Ethereum Blockchain trying to send transaction using web3.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, web3py, go-ethereum

I am able to use the web3.py library and I am able to deploy the contract directly using my node in Ethereum.

I created my solidity code in remix and copied the ABI in the Ethereum console to deploy the code. I got the address of the contract as well.

My solidity code is as follows.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;


contract bidding {

struct bid {
    string bidderName;
    uint grainId;
    uint bidAmount;
    uint bidTime;
}

mapping (uint => bid) bidInfos;
uint[] public bidIds;

function addBid(
    uint _bidId,
    string _bidderName, 
    uint _grainId, 
    uint _bidAmount
) public {
    var bid_info = bidInfos[_bidId];
    bid_info.bidderName = _bidderName;
    bid_info.grainId = _grainId;
    bid_info.bidAmount=_bidAmount;
    bid_info.bidTime= now;
    
    bidIds.push(_bidId) -1;
}

function getallBids() view public returns(uint[]) {
    return bidIds;
}

function getBid(uint _bidId) view public returns (string, uint, uint, uint) {
    return (
        bidInfos[_bidId].bidderName, 
        bidInfos[_bidId].grainId,
        bidInfos[_bidId].bidAmount, 
        bidInfos[_bidId].bidTime
    );
}

function getbidcount() view public returns (uint) {
    return bidIds.length;
}
}
```

I deployed in my Ethereum network and got the address as I am using the web3py library.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider, WebsocketProvider
import json
web3 = Web3(IPCProvider())
bid_abi=json.loads('''[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_bidId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_bidderName","type":"string"},{"name":"_grainId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_bidAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addBid","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getallBids","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_bidId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getBid","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getbidcount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"bidIds","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]''')

contract_bid=web3.eth.contract(abi=bid_abi,address='0xbcd8ffbb0f8a5410194ab5a3badf46caaa693098')

contract_bid.functions.addBid(10,"xyzz",1234,5600).transact()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1064, in transact
**self.kwargs)
  File "D:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1341, in transact_with_contract_function
txn_hash = web3.eth.sendTransaction(transact_transaction)
  File "D:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 244, in sendTransaction
[transaction],
  File "D:\WinPython\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 106, in request_blocking
raise ValueError(response["error"])
 ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'unknown account'}
```

I am doing a web3.personal.unlockAccount as well, and still it is giving me the same error.

There is only one account associated with my account as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cross-linking with https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49493/web3-py-transact-function-giving-unknown-account-error.

Answer (score 0):

this error happen when the address you are using for bid is not hosted in your server. 
try to import Keystore to own server or try with account you are hosted.